# What would be the best technique to create a 2.39:1 ratio mark on the display of my camera?

Tags: canon, canon-60d, display, lcd

I have a Canon 60D camera which display I need to mark a ratio of 2.39:1 on. Basically, I need this to know the safe area of video when recording.

I thought about taping those two lines over on the LCD with a very soft and thin tape, but I hoped someone could get a better idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Draw the desired shape on an adhesive LCD protector and stick that on.

Answer (score 6):

You could install the [Magic Lantern custom firmware](http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Lantern_Firmware_Wiki) which is now supported on the Canon 60D. In addition to being able to load up custom safe area masks which simply display directly onto your LCD, there are a whole host of other video-related features (zebra stripes, anyone?) and functions that aren't included with the native firmware.

The only potential downside is that it's not made by Canon, so it's in no way 'official.' If the thought of installing custom 'not officially supported' firmware makes you quiver in your shorts, then Magic Lantern may not be for you. I personally have been using it on my 5DmkII, my 50D and my 60D cameras since early 2010 and have never had a problem that couldn't be solved by simply turning the camera off and back on again...